# how to calculate result based on formula using angular

Tags: html, angularjs

i have 3 input values A,B,C .if i give any expression in  formula`(like A+B+C or A+100,A*B,A+B+1500)`  on change event calculate result
how to do this

```
A:<input type="text" ng-model="v.A" />
B:<input type="text" ng-model="v.B" />
B:<input type="text" ng-model="v.C" />
<br />
Formula:<input type="text" ng-model="v.Formula" ng-blur="CalculateFormula(v)" />
{{result}}
```

Angular script

```
//on change of formula
 $scope.CalculateFormula = function (v) {

      //
    }
```

can you please suggest how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

use ng-change directive on the element u want the result to be found.
eg. ng-change = v.calcresult()

Comment: am not getting you Plankton.